# Defining an EXTRACT range from a SELECT statement

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I intend to process a dataset from EventHub stored in ADLA, in batches. It seems logical to me to process intervals, where my date is between my last execution datetime and the current execution datetime.

I thought about saving the execution timestamps in a table so I can keep track of it, and do the following:

```
DECLARE @my_file string = @"/data/raw/my-ns/my-eh/{date:yyyy}/{date:MM}/{date:dd}/{date:HH}/{date:mm}/{date:ss}/{*}.avro";

DECLARE @max_datetime DateTime =  DateTime.Now;

@min_datetime =
    SELECT (DateTime) MAX(execution_datetime) AS min_datetime
    FROM my_adldb.dbo.watermark;

@my_json_bytes =
    EXTRACT Body byte[],
            date DateTime
    FROM @my_file
    USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.ApacheAvro.AvroExtractor(@"{""type"":""record"",""name"":""EventData"",""namespace"":""Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging"",""fields"":[{""name"":""SequenceNumber"",""type"":""long""},{""name"":""Offset"",""type"":""string""},{""name"":""EnqueuedTimeUtc"",""type"":""string""},{""name"":""SystemProperties"",""type"":{""type"":""map"",""values"":[""long"",""double"",""string"",""bytes""]}},{""name"":""Properties"",""type"":{""type"":""map"",""values"":[""long"",""double"",""string"",""bytes"",""null""]}},{""name"":""Body"",""type"":[""null"",""bytes""]}]}");
```

How do I properly add this interval to my `EXTRACT` query? I tested it using a common WHERE clause with interval defined by hand and it worked, but when I attempt to use `@min_datetime` it doesn't work, since its result is a rowset.

I thought about applying some filtering in a subsequent query, but I am afraid this means `@my_json_bytes` will extract my whole dataset and filter it aftewards, resulting in a suboptimized query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try applying the filter in a subsequent with a `CROSS JOIN` to `@min_datetime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to apply the filter as part of a later `SELECT`.  U-SQL *can* push up predicates in certain conditions but I haven't been able to test this yet.  Try something like this:

```
@min_datetime =
    SELECT (DateTime) MAX(execution_datetime) AS min_datetime
    FROM my_adldb.dbo.watermark;

@my_json_bytes =
    EXTRACT Body byte[],
            date DateTime
    FROM @my_file
    USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.ApacheAvro.AvroExtractor(@"{""type"":""record"",""name"":""EventData"",""namespace"":""Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging"",""fields"":[{""name"":""SequenceNumber"",""type"":""long""},{""name"":""Offset"",""type"":""string""},{""name"":""EnqueuedTimeUtc"",""type"":""string""},{""name"":""SystemProperties"",""type"":{""type"":""map"",""values"":[""long"",""double"",""string"",""bytes""]}},{""name"":""Properties"",""type"":{""type"":""map"",""values"":[""long"",""double"",""string"",""bytes"",""null""]}},{""name"":""Body"",""type"":[""null"",""bytes""]}]}");

@working =
    SELECT *
    FROM @my_json_bytes AS j
         CROSS JOIN
             @min_datetime AS t
    WHERE j.date > t.min_datetime;
```

Comment: Thank you! This will do the trick. I just hope it is optimized. I will benchmark it later if I get the time to do so.